# How To Open My WebPage Using External IP In My PC?

Tags: server, proxy, vpn, modem, ip

I am using **UbuntuServer13.10** in my server and **Windows7SP1** in my PC and both connected with a DSL modem (Dynamic External IP), So whenever I try to open my server page in my PC using internal IP of server like (192.168.1.99), I got my server webpage in browser but whenever I try to open using External IP in my PC, that is forwarded to server internal IP, I am not getting my server webpage in my PC browser.

But when I use any Proxy/VPN then I am able to open my server webpage in PC using external IP. Now my question is **How to open external IP in my own PC without Proxy/VPN?** So do you have any solution for this.

Comment: No, you can't. You need to make it looks like you come from another IP.

Comment: Have a search for "hairpinning".

Comment: Relevant http://superuser.com/questions/444206/access-internal-server-using-external-ip/444216#444216

Comment: Thanks for replying. I also didn't get any solution so keep using proxies... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching this problem everywhere, finally I got the answer that there is no solution for this problem because its for Dynamic IP, even if you have static IP, you have to do too much editing in your files that can damage your security too so its only your problem then keep using [Proxy Search Engine](http://www.exeideas.com/2011/03/list-of-proxies_12.html) for this purpose. Every other in the world is able to open your IP directly without any Proxy/VPN so make yourself comfortable.